# Why relocation of shards doesn't happens when unassigned shards are present in a cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I was reading about relocation of shards in elastic search and allocation of unassigned shards. Came upon this issue - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12273.

Here it is mentioned that since unassigned shards are present in the cluster relocation is not possible..
I couldn't comprehend the reason behind it.

I tried reading about procedures to reallocate shards when unassigned shards are present. There are some deadlock issues when we put hard limit on the total number shards on a node, but I feel they can be addressed if relocation happens.

Comment: When you have an allocation issue, the first thing to do to understand why is to call `GET _cluster/allocation/explain`. Can you update your question with the full result you get from that call?

Comment: I know the reason of my shards being unassigned.. I am researching on how does allocation of unassigned shards takes place.

Comment: If you know why and the problem has been resolved, you can simply run `POST _cluster/reroute?retry_failed=true` and the unassigned shards will start being allocated

Comment: How does the allocation takes place is what I want to know, 
What you told doesn't answers my question.

Comment: It's automatic, ES decides what to allocate where based on multiple rules. Allocation rules are described here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html#shards-rebalancing-heuristics